# Is scribblenauts an indie game?

Tags: scribblenauts

So, the first four Scribblenauts games were produced by 5th Cell and WB games. After 5th Cell declared bankrupcy, the rights to that franchise were bought out by 505 games, an indie company (Who created Terraria, Starforge, and more.) This made me curious. Is Scribblenauts (Or Drawn To Life, since they were both bought out by 505 games.) an Indie game?

Comment: depends... how do you define 'indie game'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An indie game is defined as a video game that is created without the financial support of a publisher.

From [Scribblenauts wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribblenauts):

> Scribblenauts is an emergent puzzle action video game developed by 5th Cell and published by Warner Bros.

Therefore no, it is not an indie game as it was published by Warner Bros as well as Konami for the Japanese localised release.

Comment: To further this point, 505 Games is, in fact, a publisher, not a developer.

Comment: But they HAVE developed games. Just not indie games, it appears. It's also interesting to note that they helped publish the elusive Mean Girls DS game, which people have a hard time finding anything on it. But ye, thanks for the info there!